# Spinner default text color white?

Tags: java, android

I would like to change the color of the default value of my spinner.

This value is white for no reason, how can I fix the text color of this default value to black?

Illustration:
[image]

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
List<String> list;

list=new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("0.01");
list.add("0.10");
list.add("1.00");
list.add("10.0");
list.add("100");
adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner_pas.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner_pas.setSelection(2);
```

Comment: go in simple_spinner_list_item layout file and change the color of text.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line into the xml - android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item

```
 android:background="@color/black"
 android:textColor="@color/white"
```

Comment: I want background at white and textColor at black. But this is not in the popup of my spinner but the default value directly is white. I drawed it maybe it can help you

Comment: Do you want a border in black

Comment: I prefer border in white

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom theme for Spinner like this

```
<style name="CustomSpinnerTheme" 
  parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.DropDownItem.Spinner">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:background">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

and apply it here

```
 adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), 
 android.R.style.CustomSpinnerTheme,list);
```